# WooCommerce / Wordpress images rotated for no reason?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I know this is probably not the best SO question ever because I don't have the relevant code (I don't know where it is and I can't find it). If anybody has seen this problem before or knows what is causing this I can't tell you how much I would appreciate it.

I have a storefront and the images in the storefront are showing up rotated 90 degrees to the left for no apparent reason.

The actual source files of the images are normal, if you look at the actual .jpg used in on the site they are upright.

How or why would they be showing up rotated? Is this some setting or a bug in WooCommerce?

**Note**

Yes, I've disabled every addon and used only WordPress and WooCommerce and the result is the same. Different themes yield the same result as well.

Comment: Worked with both and have *never* seen anything like this. What's the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem in case anybody stumbles across this later down the road. The issue is with Apple's exif data and rotation information they store within each image. It is apparently not compatible with most computers and when you upload a picture from a mobile device from Apple (ipad, iphone etc.) you are likely to experience this phenomenon.

There is little than can be done about it, shy of uploading the images to a computer and manually fixing the orientation of all rotated images before using them.

Comment: This is an epic answer. Thanks!